# Easiest way to select parent nodes multiple parents up in the tree in D3

Tags: d3.js, selection, nodes, parent

I'm trying to select the parent four levels up in the tree from my current selection.

Short of doing

`d3.select(d3.select(this.parentNode)[0][0].parentNode)`

up to four levels, is there an easier way to access the parent of a parent of a parent, or such similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the nested selections and do `d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode...etc)`, but that's about it - .parentNode is the only way to go and according to the author it's by design: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/mEjem7IPshY